# How to convert an ndarray to a "tall" Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Some work I am doing results in an output tensor (numpy ndarray) of varying dimensions depending on the things I am interested in / want to plot over time, sometimes I may choose age groups and gender as my targets, which will results in a 3D tensor where we have

```
age_groups[
  genders[
    days[Value, ..., Value], 
    days[Value, ..., Value]
  ],
  ...,
  genders[
    days[Value, ..., Value]
    days[Value, ..., Value]
  ],
]
```

My question is, how can I most effectively turn this into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     Age_Group  Gender  Day  Value
0    1          M       1    blah
1    1          F       1    blah
2    1          M       2    blah
4    1          F       2    blah
5    1          M       3    blah
6    1          F       3    blah
7    1          M       4    blah
...
n    5          F       21   blah
```

And how can I ensure it could generalise to if I add another target to group by, say Hair Colour, so that another column would be added to the resulting df?

Sorry if this question is somewhat abstract, I hope that I illustrated my problem clearly enough, if not I can try to clarify further.

Comment: Is the data a numpy array? Or can it be converted to such?

Comment: @SeanSdahl yes it is, should have stated I have it as a numpy ndarray, will edit to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a MultiIndex dataframe from your a flattened version of your array. There's no real indication on what the values are for your variables at each index of your 3D array, but assuming an arbitrary order:

```
arr = np.arange(4*2*21).reshape(4, 2, 21)  # example array
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['M', 'F'], np.arange(1, 22)],
    names=['Age_Group', 'Gender', 'Day']
)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr.flatten(), index=ix, columns=['Value'])
```

Output:

```
     Age_Group Gender  Day  Value
0            1      M    1      0
1            1      M    2      1
2            1      M    3      2
3            1      M    4      3
4            1      M    5      4
..         ...    ...  ...    ...
163          4      F   17    163
164          4      F   18    164
165          4      F   19    165
166          4      F   20    166
167          4      F   21    167
```

If the order of your variable values at each index is different, just change your input for the function `from_product` to match your array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is called data:

```
data = ...
array = np.hstack([np.arange(data.size).reshape(-1, 1) % np.prod(data.shape[i:]) // np.prod(data.shape[i+1:])  for i in range(data.ndim)])
array = np.concatenate([array, data.reshape(-1, 1)])
df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['column names'])
```

Now you will just have to convert the gender columns to letters if you want